# Google Charts: Assign value to different axis

Tags: javascript, api, charts, google-visualization

I've run into a bit of a problem that is driving me slightly crazy.
I've created a chart that looks like I want it to, the problem is that its mirrored. It's a combo chart and has 1 value represented by column/bar and 1 value thats a line, however the line values are on the left vAxis and the bar values on the right vAxis. While this is not a dealbreaker I would like it the be the other way around and I cant make it work!

The following is the entire code for the chart!

```
  google.charts.load('current', { 'packages':['corechart']
        });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);


  function drawVisualization()
        {
            // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

             ['Day', 'Bolivia', 'Average'],

             ['1', 26000, 70 ],

             ['2', 21000, 80],

             ['3', 19000, 75],

             ['4', 25000, 60],

             ['5', 24000, 90]
  ]);

  var options = {
  title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
  vAxes: {
      0: { logScale: false },
      1: { logScale: false, maxValue: 2 }
  },
  hAxis: { title: 'Month'},
  seriesType: 'bars',
  series: {
      0: { targetAxisIndex: 1 },
      0: { targetAxisIndex: 1 },
      1: { targetAxisIndex: 0 },
      1: { type: 'line' }
  }
  };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

And I believe the problem is in this part:

```
  series: {
      0: { targetAxisIndex: 1 },
      0: { targetAxisIndex: 1 },
      1: { targetAxisIndex: 0 },
      1: { type: 'line' }
  }
```

I've tried so many combinations of 0 and 1 here and there but it doesn't work! Am I missing something?!

Answer (score 0):

there should only be one object `{}` per series number

```
series: {
  0: {
    targetAxisIndex: 1
  },
  1: {
    targetAxisIndex: 0,
    type: 'line'
  }
}
```